# The number of positive zeros is at most 2.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials

Let all $c_i$'s are arbitrary real numbers (not zero simultaneously) and $p_1 < p_2$ are positive integers. If $f_r(x) = c_2 + c_1(x+p_1)^r$, where $r>1$. Then it's easy to observe that $f_r(x)$ has at most one positive zero. 
Let $g_r(x) = c_3+(x+p_2)^r[c_2 + c_1(x+p_1)^r]$. So $g_r(x) = c_3+(x+p_2)^r f_r(x)$. How can I prove that $g_r(x)$ has at most $2$ positive zeros for every $r>1$.

As it's clear that $g_r(x)$ is obtained by multiplying $f_r(x)$ by an increasing function and then adding an arbitrary constant to it. How can I use this to show that this process will increase the number of positive zeros by at most one?

Any hint or tip will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Between any two consecutive positive zeroes of $g$, there must a a zero of $g'$, but
$$\begin{align}g'(x)&=r(x+p_2)^{r-1}(c_2+c_1(x+p_1)^r)+(x+p_2)^rc_1r(x+p_1)^{r-1}(x+p_1)^r\\
&=c_2r(x+p_2)^{r-1}+c_1r(x+p_2)^{r-1}(x+p_1)^r+c_1r(x+p_2)^r(x+p_1)^{r-1}\\
&=r(x+p_2)^{r-1}\cdot\Bigl(c_2+c_1(x+p_1)^r+c_1(x+p_2)(x+p_1)^{r-1}\Bigr)\\
&=\underbrace{r(x+p_2)^{r-1}}_{>0}\cdot\Bigl(c_2+c_1\cdot\underbrace{(x+p_1)^{r-1}(2x+p_1+p_2)}_{\text{increasing}}\Bigr)\end{align}$$
has at most one positive zero$^1$. (Note that we'd run into problems if $r-1$ were negative)

---

$^1$ or is identically zero, but then $g$ is constant non-zero.

Comment: i think in instead $2x+p_1+p_2$ it should be $1+x+p_2$. Also $c_1$ may be negative

Comment: but anyways, in both cases, it will have at most one positive zero. I got ur point. Thanks :)

Comment: @prince $c_1$ is outside the "increasing" brace (now clarified by multiplication dots). The key is that $c_2+c_1\cdot\text{increasing}$ is injective if $c_1\ne 0$. -- And $(x+p_1)+(x+p_2)=2x+p_1+p_2$